# Vanishing of the product of a function and its own Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, lebesgue-measure

I have found the following question to be surprisingly hard:

**Is there a non-zero $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ or $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that
$$
f\cdot\hat f=0 \qquad \text{Lebesgue-almost everywhere},
$$
where $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ and $\cdot$ is the pointwise product?**

I expect the answer to be no, but it seems hard to prove. **Edit: Actually the answer is yes, and one can even choose $f$ to be a Schwartz function, see below.**

Note that if $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ or if $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ is sufficiently nice then $\cdot$ can equivalently be replaced by convolution $\ast$.

It is known (see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275072/function-and-fourier-transform-vanish-on-an-interval)) that there is a Schwartz function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that both $f$ and $\hat f$ vanish on some open interval. This is similar to but obviously weaker than the above question.

**Edit: as pointed out in the comments, it is easy to see that the existing answers to the MO question referenced above also answer my question affirmatively.**

Comment: I think the same construction works, see "my" (reuns's really) answer at the linked question. We only need to give $g, h$ disjoint supports.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: in that answer it is obvious that $\mathrm{supp}\,\hat f\subset \mathrm{supp}\,h_p$ but I don't see why one should have $\mathrm{supp}\,f\subset \mathrm{supp}\,g$.

Comment: @B K: If we take $\textrm{supp}\; g \subseteq [a,b]\subseteq [0,1]$, then $f=\sum c_n g(x-n)$ has support contained in $\bigcup [a+n,b+n]$, which we can ensure will be disjoint from $\textrm{supp}\; h_p$.

Comment: By the way, I think a suitably adapted version of Dirk's answer to my question works equally well here. Of course, we need to modulate the Dirac comb by multiplying it by $e^{iax}$ to shift the FT, and then we cautiously make everything smooth.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: thank you, that's cool. If you summarize your comments in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @B K: Thanks, but it would just be duplicating the old answers, so I think just the reference to those will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to stratch my head a bit to decipher what we wrote 4 years ago but there it is

- Take  $\hat{\phi} \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R})$ supported on $(1/2,1)$
- Take $h \in C^\infty(\Bbb{R})$ and $1$-periodic supported on $[0,1/2]+\Bbb{Z}$, let $c_n=\int_0^1 h(x)e^{-2i\pi nx}dx$. Then

$$\hat{h}=\sum_n c_n \delta(y-n)$$ So that

$$\hat{h}\ast \hat{\phi}= \sum_n c_n \hat{\phi}(y-n)$$ It is Schwartz because $(c_n)$ is rapidly decreasing, it is also non-zero and supported on $(1/2,1)+\Bbb{Z}$.

On the other hand its inverse Fourier transform $h\phi$ is supported on $[0,1/2]+\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Basically, if I am not wrong, your construction is the following: Pick $f,g \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and define $$h=\check{f}( g * \delta_{\mathbb Z})$$ which is easy to check that it is a Schwarz function. Then $sup(h) \subseteq \mathbb Z + sup(g)$. Next $$\hat{h}=f*( \widehat{g} \delta_{\mathbb Z})$$ is supported inside $$sup(\hat{h}) \subseteq \mathbb Z + sup(f)$$