# Condition on the support of $f$ which ensure that $\widehat{f}$ has a zero-measure nodal region

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is non-zero and compactly supported. Then its Fourier transform $\widehat{f}\neq 0$ is analytic, and in particular the nodal set $\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}\,s.t.\,\widehat{f}(\xi)=0\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero. I'm wondering whether the same conclusion can be obtained by slightly relaxing the compactly supported condition. So my (a bit vague) question is the following:

**Are there some sufficient conditions (weaker than compactness) on the support of $f$  which guarantee that $\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}\,s.t.\,\widehat{f}(\xi)=0\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero?**

Comment: Of course you want to assume $f$ is not a.e. $0$.

Comment: There exist compactly supported functions in the Gevrey class of order $s>1$, whose Fourier transform decays like $\exp(-|\xi|^{1/s})$. Thus if you are looking for suitable decay conditions, it seems there is not much room

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sure, thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: This question of mine suggests that not much is possible along these lines: there are Schwartz functions such that $f$ has a support of small measure, but $\widehat{f}$ vanishes on an interval. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275072/function-and-fourier-transform-vanish-on-an-interval

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona Thank you for your comment Piero. This essentially rules out the possibility that decay conditions could give a positive result.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you, very nice construction. If I understand correctly, there is still a small room for some positive result. For example, one could assume that $f$ vanishes outside a ball except for a positive measures set which is nowhere dense. Do you think that something can be said under this assumption?

Comment: @RaffaeleScandone: Yes, indeed, this doesn't literally answer the question you asked for exactly the reason you point out. I don't know what to expect in this situation.